ADO YAML template's pipeline trigger is not being honored?
We have a YAML template pipeline that begins with the following:
trigger: none
Despite that, our pipeline has randomly started triggering on individual CI for any branch any our repository. Has anyone experienced incorrect behavior like this? Or is there something I am missing? From my understanding, trigger: none should prevent ANY trigger, full stop. I have also verified we do not have any overrides set in the ADO pipeline settings outside of the yaml template (see below image)


Haven't looked further into it at the moment, but I will circle back and investigate other branches when time allows!

I will wait for your feedback.


Our pipeline has randomly started triggering on individual CI for any branch any our repository.

I have encountered similar issues before. The YAML Pipeline trigger is set to none but it still gets triggered.
The possible cause of the issue is that multiple branches have the pipeline Yaml files with the same name and the trigger field has been defined with the branch settings in other branches.
For example:
Main branch: YAML file name: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger: none

Test branch: YAML file name: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - test

In this case, even though the main branch is set trigger to none, it will still be triggered by test branch.
To solve this issue, you need to change the name of the YAML files in each branch and make sure the name is not repeated in the same repo.
For example:
Main branch -> YAML file name: azure-pipelines-main.yml
Test branch -> YAML file name: azure-pipelines-test.yml
On the other hand, you can also check if you have defined the Repo Resources in YAML Pipeline and set the trigger branch.
For example:
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: common
    type: git
    name: xx/xx
    trigger:
      branches:
       include:
        - main

In this case, the repo resource commit will CI trigger the YAML Pipeline. If you don't need this trigger. You can remove the trigger field.

Thanks, Kevin! The latter isn't a concern, but it is very possible we have old branches lying around with discrepancies.

@LoganCodes You can check the old branches when you have time.  Feel free to let me know the result.  If you have any further questions, I will try to give help.
